# Customize spacy stop words and save the model

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, stop-words, spacy-3

I am using this to add stopwords to the spacy's list of stopwords

`nlp.Defaults.stop_words |= {"my_new_stopword1","my_new_stopword2",}`

However, when I save the nlp object using `nlp.to_disk()` and load it back again with `nlp.from_disk()`,
I am loosing the list of custom stop words.
Is there a way to save the custom stopwords with the nlp model?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Most language defaults (stop words, lexical attributes, and syntax iterators) are not saved with the model.

If you want to customize them, you can create a custom language class, see: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#language-subclass. An example copied from this link:

```py
from spacy.lang.en import English

class CustomEnglishDefaults(English.Defaults):
    stop_words = set(["custom", "stop"])

class CustomEnglish(English):
    lang = "custom_en"
    Defaults = CustomEnglishDefaults

nlp1 = English()
nlp2 = CustomEnglish()

print(nlp1.lang, [token.is_stop for token in nlp1("custom stop")])
print(nlp2.lang, [token.is_stop for token in nlp2("custom stop")])
```

Comment: This solution worked. However, this nlp object doesnt contain the word vectors.